# How to add custom onTap in marker flutter map?

Tags: flutter

I have a map in flutter where I have to commute the user to a specific point using directions. The red marker on the map when on pressed automatically shows directions on the bottom right but I want to show an arrow head to the user to click the directions on the bottom right because user may not notice it by themselves: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVAvx.jpg

This is the code snippet :

```
 void getLocation() async {
    var location = await currentLocation.getLocation();
    currentLocation.onLocationChanged.listen((LocationData loc) {
      mapcontroller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(CameraPosition(
          target: LatLng(loc.latitude ?? 0.0, loc.longitude ?? 0.0), zoom: 5)));

      setState(() {
        clat = loc.latitude;
        clng = loc.longitude;
        _markers.addAll({
          Marker(
            markerId: const MarkerId('Shopkeeper Position'),
            icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
            // position: LatLng(20.7708612, 73.7235274))
            position: LatLng(
              widget.latitude,
              widget.longitude,
            ),
            onTap: () {
              print("");
              print("");
              print("Marker pressed");
              print("");
              print("");
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "Get Directions",
                      style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                        fontSize: 40,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Image.asset(
                      'assets/arrowHead.gif',
                      width: 200,
                      height: 200,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          )
        });
      });
      getPolypoints();
    });
  }
```

All i get when I tap on the marker are the print statements. I would want to display the row widget as well. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with help of the builder property:

```html
Marker myMarker = Marker(
  point: LatLng(latitude, longitude),
  builder: (context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        // Handle marker tap event here
        // You can show a dialog, navigate to a new screen, etc.
      },
      child: YourMarkerWidget(),
    );
  },

);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your directions container and show/hide depending on the onTap.

Something like this:

```
isTapped ?? directionsContainer : Container() // empty container if isTapped is false
```

Update your onTap: to update state with a boolean:

```
setState(() {
    isTapped = !isTapped;
})
```